# vb.net sql database log in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, authentication

I have got a table within my sql database with:

- Primary Key: ID
- Foreign Key: Haulier ID
- Column1: Username
- Column2: Password

The ID is unique, the Foreign Key can either be 1 (JKP) or 2 (Clarke), the Username and Password are different every time.

My form has got a drop down box that includes the names of the companies: JKP, Clarke

If JKP is selected it passes 1 to a text box

If Clarke is selected it passes 2 to a text box

Then Username and Password text boxes.

I have got a similar log in working but I cannot seem to get this to work. I assumed that the text box value would suffice the Foreign key column, and the username and password would come from the text boxes. This is the code I have got, when I run it I just get the message box saying that the username or password is incorrect.

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
     Try

        Dim haulier As Integer
        If combohaulier.SelectedItem = "John K Philps" Then
            haulier = 1
        Else
            haulier = 2
        End If

        Dim objconnection1 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Cara\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        objconnection1.Open()

        Dim SelectStmt1 As String = "SELECT * FROM [2HaulierLogIn] WHERE HaulierID='" & haulier & "' AND Username='" & txt_cusername.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password='" & txt_cpassword.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ;"
        Dim objcommand1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SelectStmt1, objconnection1)
        Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = objcommand1.ExecuteReader

        If reader1.Read Then
            If haulier = 1 And txt_hpassword.Text <> reader1("Password").ToString And txt_husername.Text <> reader1("Username").ToString Then
                frm_Rhauljkphome.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                txt_husername.Clear()
                txt_hpassword.Clear()
            End If

        ElseIf reader1.Read Then
            If haulier = 2 And txt_hpassword.Text <> reader1("Password").ToString And txt_husername.Text <> reader1("Username").ToString Then
                Me.Hide()
                frm_Shaulclarkehome.Show()
                txt_husername.Clear()
                txt_hpassword.Clear()
            End If

            Else
                Static count1 As Integer = 0
                Dim prompt1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Invaild Username or Password.", "Login Error",
                                                             MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                Select Case prompt1
                    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry
                        txt_husername.Text = ""
                        txt_hpassword.Text = ""
                        count1 += 1
                        If count1 = 3 Then
                            MessageBox.Show("High value of failed login attempts." & vbCrLf & "Application will be terminated for security reasons.", "Error",
                                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
                            End
                        End If
                    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
                        Application.Exit()
                End Select
            End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, 
If *HaulierID* is a Foreign key and may have a value of 1 (JKP) or 2 (Clarke), 
would it need those **single quotes wrapped on the TextBox1.Text** value on the **sql** statement?

```
Dim SelectStmt1 As String = "SELECT * FROM [2HaulierLogIn] WHERE Username='" & _
    txt_cusername.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password='" & _
    txt_cpassword.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND HaulierID=" & _
    TextBox1.Text & ";"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have taken those things out but it has made no difference. I think it's got something to do with the reader. I have changed it slightly from what is posted above. I will edit the question with what I have now. I have been on this for days now. I really need to get it working.